# Masterpage wont inherit?

Tags: master-page, inheritance

I've created a masterpage that displays fine, although if I create a new site, it doesnt inherit. If I go into the masterpage settings then check the box to reset inheritance, it will deploy to all of the existing sites and look right; however, what I need is for it to automatically inherit (all on its own) whenever the site owners create a new site. I cant keep resetting the masterpage to reinherit across the site collection. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create an Event Receiver.

In Visual Studio, right click project => Add new item => Event Receiver => Web Events, Handle the following events: A Site is being provisioned.

The following override will be generated and fire on every new site creation. Just insert the code within:

```
    public override void WebProvisioned(SPWebEventProperties properties)
    {            
        //2)Set master page
        SPWeb web = properties.Web;
        web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/CustomMasterPage.master";
        web.Update();
        base.WebProvisioned(properties);
    }
```

Comment: This answer is right, another way to do it instead of setting the custom master page, is just to enable the OOTB Web publishing feature ("94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb") in this event (webProvisioned) in order to inherit the custom parent master page.

Answer (score 1):

if  you don't want to use the webprovisioned method / event receiver then their is one more alternative.

You have to manually update the your master page. check the below blog for more detail.

http://jeffreypaarhuis.com/2011/10/21/your-master-page-automatically-on-newly-created-subsites/